# mysql syntax error: 'USING BTREE ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTOINCREMENT='

Tags: mysql

Im getting this error:

```
CREATE TABLE `pdc5l_usergroups` (
`id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Clave primaria',
`parent_id` int( 10 ) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'ID Lista de referencia adyacente',
`lft` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Anidadas conjunto lft.',
`rgt` int( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Anidadas conjunto rgt.',
`title` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY `idx_usergroup_parent_title_lookup` ( `parent_id` , `title` ) ,
KEY `idx_usergroup_title_lookup` ( `title` ) ,
KEY `idx_usergroup_adjacency_lookup` ( `parent_id` ) ,
KEY `idx_usergroup_nested_set_lookup` ( `lft` , `rgt` ) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =9 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8AUTOINCREMENT =9;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTOINCREMENT=' at line 11
```

I have tried these:

```
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =9 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =9;
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTOINCREMENT =9 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTOINCREMENT =9;
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTOINCREMENT =9 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =9;
```

but I still get the error.

phpmyadmin says this: `MySQL client version: 4.1.22`

Answer (score 1):

This is a mysql version problem. You can see the issue in that bug:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25162

> Before MySQL 5.0.60, this option can be given only before the ON
>   tbl_name clause. Use of the option in this position is deprecated as
>   of 5.0.60 and support for it there will be removed in a future MySQL
>   release. If an index_type option is given in both the earlier and
>   later positions, the final option applies.
>
> TYPE type_name is recognized as a synonym for USING type_name.
>   However, USING is the preferred form.

For more details see here: http://www.dbforums.com/mysql/1617755-using-btree.html

Comment: Limited support also applies to [the 5.1 branch](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). Support for this syntax was added in 5.1.10 on this branch.